# Full path to the folder where the currently active file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a task in Visual Studio Code, but I need a path to the actual file. Is there some option?

My task:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "${workspaceRoot}/run.sh",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${hereINeedPathToActualFile}"
    },
    "args": ["${file}"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

`window.title` is the setting that worked for me in User Settings:
`"window.title": "${activeEditorMedium}"`

Other options:

```
  // Controls the window title based on the active editor. Variables are substituted based on the context:
  // ${activeEditorShort}: e.g. myFile.txt
  // ${activeEditorMedium}: e.g. myFolder/myFile.txt
  // ${activeEditorLong}: e.g. /Users/Development/myProject/myFolder/myFile.txt
  // ${rootName}: e.g. myProject
  // ${rootPath}: e.g. /Users/Development/myProject
  // ${appName}: e.g. VS Code
  // ${dirty}: a dirty indicator if the active editor is dirty
  // ${separator}: a conditional separator (" - ") that only shows when surrounded by variables with values
  "window.title": "${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}",
```

Comment: The question is about a task command-line, not about window display.

Answer (score 6):

Go to *Settings*. Inside UserSettings, add this line to the JSON  blob:

> "window.title": "${activeEditorLong}"

Comment: The question is about a task command-line, not about window display.

Comment: I landed here, due to the question title, and this answer was helpful. I was looking to display the full path to the active file in VSCode.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to access a file, you could derive its location from the workspace root:

```
"filelocation": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/tasks.json",

// Available variables which can be used inside of strings.
// ${workspaceRoot}: the root folder of the team
// ${file}: the current opened file
// ${fileBasename}: the current opened file's basename
// ${fileDirname}: the current opened file's dirname
// ${fileExtname}: the current opened file's extension
// ${cwd}: the current working directory of the spawned process
```

Comment: Hi, i need variable to "cwd"

Answer (score 5):

This issue has been addressed several months ago:

> *[Display the full workspace path in UI #3119](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3119)*
>
> There is a new setting `window.showFullPath` that once enabled will show the full path to the currently opened file instead of the workspace relative path.

The feature is planned to ship in the November release, currently in testing. Then you could control it with `window.showFullPath` in your configuration file.

---

UPDATE:

The setting has been changed since I posted the original answer. It's now called **window.title**, which you could customize whatever you like.

Comment: this doesn't work for me on my Macbook I wrote "window.showFullPath": true,  it complains that is an unknown setting.

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi I posted this answer over half a year ago. The setting has been changed since then. It's now called **window.title**, which you could customize whatever you like.

Comment: The historical account is not that interesting (that is what we have the edit history for). This answer ought to be written as if it was answered today.

Comment: The question is about a task command-line, not about window display.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following in my "launch.json" file to set the current working directory (cwd) prior to launching a Python program:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
```

So the path to the actual file's directory is in ${fileDirname}.

I don't use ${workspaceRoot}, because it's deprecated and it is the path to the root of the work space, not the current working directory if the current working directory is a folder other than the root.

There is a list of all of the Visual Studio Code Task variables in *[Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)*.